# Binding a dropdownlist in a table using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am facing a problem while binding a HTML dropdown in a table.
Need to change color of the Column1 based on status and also setting the default value of the dropdown with actual value coming from JSON.

JS fiddle link for the same is:

http://jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/uguxA/1/

```
 <div class="divStat" data-bind="style: {background: selectedChoice() === 'Pricing Complete' ? 'Green': 'Red'}">
```

Kindly check and let me know the issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: jsFiddle link is not working.Please  share it for public and re post.

Comment: Can you please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Change Style Binding*

```
<div class="divStat" 
    data-bind="style: {background:selectedChoice().Name === 'Pricing Complete' ? 'Green': 'Red'}">
</div>
```

and in the **ViewModel** mapping json to model, i used to assign javascript object directly

This is option model

```
 self.pricingstatus = [
        { Name: 'Pricing Complete' },
        { Name: 'Pricing Incomplete' }

];
```

this is for binding with json to model

```
  self.BindPricingSiemensProductsDetailsData = function (data) {
    var tempArray = [];

    self.simpleSearchResultsArray([]);
    if (data) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k = k + 1) {
            var temppricingProdDetails = new PricingSiemensProductDetails();
            temppricingProdDetails.ItemNo(data[k].ItemNo);                
            temppricingProdDetails.BOMID(data[k].BOMID);
            if(data[k].priceStat === "Draft")
            {
            temppricingProdDetails.selectedChoice(self.pricingstatus[1]);
                console.log(temppricingProdDetails.selectedChoice().Name);
            }
            else
            {
                temppricingProdDetails.selectedChoice(self.pricingstatus[0]);
                 console.log(temppricingProdDetails.selectedChoice().Name);
            }
            tempArray.push(temppricingProdDetails);
            self.simpleSearchResultsArray.push(temppricingProdDetails);
        }
    }
};
```

If i don't take your question wrong - [Here is sample in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Teus/1/)

You can also learn and reference through [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

You can also find in [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) from knockoutjs learning website.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `selectedChoice()` is not what you expect it to be. So it always display red color witch is the default choice.

Comment: How can this be corrected? i am changing the selectedchoice() to the slected value frm dropdown

Comment: @Experts:any clue on this will be very useful for me to proceed